# flutter: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget?' error

Tags: ios, flutter, widget, future, subtype

i am getting " type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Widget?' " in my ios simulator. how do i get rid of this? plz help.
this is my code.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold( ...

 body: cropImage(PickedFile)
 
);



cropImage(pickedFile) async {
File? croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
  sourcePath: pickedFile,
  maxWidth: 1080,
  maxHeight: 1080,
);
if (croppedImage != null) {
  var image = croppedImage;
  setState(() {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must give subtype of Widget in body parameter ,cause `cropimage()` type is Future, not Widget

Like this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold( ...

 body: Text('Hello')
 
);
```

or

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold( ...

 body: Center(child:Text('Hello'))
 
);
```